# how can i save parent and set of childs at a time using casedeType in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

i have two entities namely **ExmStudentMarksEntry** and **ExmStudentMarksEntrySubcat**

please look at entities

parent **ExmStudentMarksEntry**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "exm_student_marks_entry")
public class ExmStudentMarksEntry implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer studentMarksId;

    private String marks;
    private Set<ExmStudentMarksEntrySubcat> exmStudentMarksEntrySubcats = new HashSet<ExmStudentMarksEntrySubcat>(0);

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "exmStudentMarksEntry",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<ExmStudentMarksEntrySubcat> getExmStudentMarksEntrySubcats() {  
        return this.exmStudentMarksEntrySubcats;
    }

    public void setExmStudentMarksEntrySubcats(Set<ExmStudentMarksEntrySubcat> exmStudentMarksEntrySubcats) {
        this.exmStudentMarksEntrySubcats = exmStudentMarksEntrySubcats;
    }
}
```

and child entity **ExmStudentMarksEntrySubcat**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "exm_student_marks_entry_subcat")
public class ExmStudentMarksEntrySubcat implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer studentMarksSubcatId;
    private ExmStudentMarksEntry exmStudentMarksEntry;
    private String marks;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_marks_id", nullable = false)
    public ExmStudentMarksEntry getExmStudentMarksEntry() {
        return this.exmStudentMarksEntry;
    }

    public void setExmStudentMarksEntry(ExmStudentMarksEntry exmStudentMarksEntry) {
        this.exmStudentMarksEntry = exmStudentMarksEntry;
    }
}
```

i want to save parent and child entities at time using hibernate CascadeType
so i tried by giving **CascadeType.All** to child in the parent class but its not working for me .

i set child  object to the parent and saved it as follows

```
@Override
    public boolean addExamMarks(ExmStudentMarksEntry esm) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 boolean success = false;
                 try {

                        currentSession=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

                        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(esm);     
                        success=true;     
                 }           
                 catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return success;
    }

    }
```

ints only inserting parent but not childs . gives following exception

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.rasvek.cg.entity.ExmStudentMarksEntrySubcat.exmStudentMarksEntry
```

please help me out .how can i achieve this with hibernate?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cascading actions only happen when updating or deleting objects, not when adding. For adding, you'll have to manually set the objects. E.g.:

```
try {
    currentSession=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    for(ExmStudentMarksEntrySubcat subcat : esm.getExmStudentMarksEntrySubcats()) {
        subcat.setExmStudentMarksEntry(esm);
    }
    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(esm);     
    success=true;     
}
```